# Check the particular value of attribute and extract sibblings value using XPath in Perl using XML::LibXML

Tags: perl, xpath, libxml2

If `solve` is `user`, I need the value of `name` (`LINES`).

if `solve` is `imm` and name is `ARCH`, I need the value of `value` (`6M`)

I tried in the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->parse_file(...);
my $j = 0;
my @imm;
$imm[$j++] = $_->data
    foreach 
        $doc->findnodes(
            "//meters/meter"
            ."/name[../value[\@solve/string() = 'immediate']]"
            ."/text()");
```

Errors are

```
Possible unintended interpolation of @solve in string
Global symbol "@solve" requires explicit package name
```

Sample XML:

```
<rules> 
      <meters>        
             <meter>
                   <name>LINES</spirit:name>
                   <display>LINES</display>
                   <description>Specifies the number of lines</description>
                   <value
                         solve="user"
                         id="LINES"
                         order="11"
                         format="long"
                         dataType="integer" 
                         min="2" 
                         max="34">34</value>
            </meter>
            <meter>
                  <name>ARCH</name>
                  <display>Define ARCH</display>
                  <description>Define ARCH</description>
                  <value 
                        format="string" 
                        solve="imm" 
                        id="ARCH" 
                        >6M</value>
             </meter>
       </meters>    
</rules>

<rules> 
      <meters>        
             <meter>
                   <name>LINES</spirit:name>
                   <display>LINES</display>
                   <description>Specifies the number of lines</description>
                   <value
                         solve="user"
                         id="LINES"
                         order="11"
                         format="long"
                         dataType="integer" 
                         min="2" 
                         max="34">34</value>
            </meter>
            <meter>
                  <name>ARCH</name>
                  <display>Define ARCH</display>
                  <description>Define ARCH</description>
                  <value 
                        format="string" 
                        solve="imm" 
                        id="ARCH" 
                        >6M</value>
             </meter>
       </meters>    
</rules>
```

Comment: if solve = "user" i need the value of name(i.e., LINES). if solve = "imm" and if name is ARCH i need the value of value (i.e., 6M) using xml::lib xml

i tried in this way 

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->parse_file();
  my $j= 0;
 my @imm;
 $imm[$j++] = $_->data foreach ( $doc->findnodes("//meters/meter/name[../value[\@solve/string() = 'immediate']]/text()"));
errors are 
ossible unintended interpolation of @solve in string 
Global symbol "@solve" requires explicit package name

Comment: i am unable to place the code

Comment: <rules> 
      <meters>        
             <meter>
                   <name>LINES</spirit:name>
                   <display>LINES</display>
                   <description>Specifies the number of lines</description>
                   <value
                         solve="user"
                         id="LINES"
                         order="11"
                         format="long"
                         dataType="integer" 
                         min="2" 
                         max="34">34</value>
            </meter>

Comment: <meter>
                  <name>ARCH</name>
                  <display>Define ARCH</display>
                  <description>Define ARCH</description>
                  <value 
                        format="string" 
                        solve="imm" 
                        id="ARCH" 
                        >6M</value>
             </meter>
       </meters>    
</rules>`

Comment: Fixed the code. Now add the question to the node.

Comment: Use Ctrl-K or the "{}" button to mark a block as code. (It indents it by 4.)

Comment: You are mistaken. Your code does not give that error. It would give that error if you had `".../value[@solve/...]..."`, but you correctly avoid the error with the `\ ` before the `@`.

Comment: $user[$i++] = $_->data foreach ( $doc->findnodes("/parameters/parameter/name[../value[\@solve = 'user']]/text()"));
i tried this way but errors are
 XPath error : Undefined namespace prefix,
 error : xmlXPathCompiledEval: evaluation failed

Comment: Don't ask your question in the comments! It's unreadable. I put lots of effort on your behalf already. Fix this mess, don't add to it! Delete the comments, and fix your question.

Comment: And before you say another word, make sure what you post actually gives the error you get. This new code does not give this new error either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->parse_file('XXX.xml');
my $j = 0;
my @imm;
$imm[$j++] = $_->data
    for $doc->findnodes(
            "//meters/meter"
            ."/name[../value[\@solve = 'imm']]"
            ."/text()");
print for @imm;
```

I made the following changes to your code:

1. I removed the `/string()` part from the XPath expression. It is invalid usage of a function as indicated by the error I got.
2. The value of `solve` is `imm` in your sample data, not `immediate`.

BTW, changing the middle of the XPath expression to

```
'/name[../value[@solve = "immediate"]]'
```

avoids the need of the backslash.

Comment: but i am getting these errors :
XPath error : Undefined namespace prefix
 error : xmlXPathCompiledEval: evaluation failed;
for the same code;i used this xpath;
'//meters/meter/name[../value[@solve= "imm"]]/text()'

Comment: Your XML contains namespace declarations (search for `xmlns`). See [XML::LibXML::XPathContext](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML::XPathContext) on how to handle namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

a quick and dirty hack to solve your issue - with `XML::Simple`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Simple ;
use Data::Dumper;

my $xml = XMLin(qq|
<xml>
<rules> 
      <meters>        
             <meter>
                   <name>LINES</name>
                   <display>LINES</display>
                   <description>Specifies the number of lines</description>
                   <value
                         solve="user"
                         id="LINES"
                         order="11"
                         format="long"
                         dataType="integer" 
                         min="2" 
                         max="34">34</value>
            </meter>
            <meter>
                  <name>ARCH</name>
                  <display>Define ARCH</display>
                  <description>Define ARCH</description>
                  <value 
                        format="string" 
                        solve="imm" 
                        id="ARCH" 
                        >6M</value>
             </meter>
       </meters>    
</rules>

<rules> 
      <meters>        
             <meter>
                   <name>LINES</name>
                   <display>LINES</display>
                   <description>Specifies the number of lines</description>
                   <value
                         solve="user"
                         id="LINES"
                         order="11"
                         format="long"
                         dataType="integer" 
                         min="2" 
                         max="34">34</value>
            </meter>
            <meter>
                  <name>ARCH</name>
                  <display>Define ARCH</display>
                  <description>Define ARCH</description>
                  <value 
                        format="string" 
                        solve="imm" 
                        id="ARCH" 
                        >6M</value>
             </meter>
       </meters>    
</rules>
</xml>|,
ForceArray => 1);

foreach my $rule( @{ $xml->{rules} } ){
  foreach my $meter ( @{ $rule->{meters} } ){
    foreach my $m ( @{ $meter->{meter} } ){    
      if ( $m->{value}->{LINES} and $m->{value}->{LINES}->{solve} eq 'user' ) {
        print "user solver: ".$m->{name}->[0]."\n";
      } elsif ( $m->{value}->{ARCH}->{solve} and $m->{name}->[0] and $m->{value}->{ARCH}->{solve} eq 'imm' and $m->{name}->[0] eq 'ARCH' ) {
        print "imm solver: ".Dumper( $m->{value}->{ARCH}->{content})."\n";
      } else {
        print "no solver???".Dumper($m);
      }
    }    
  }
}
```

I hope you can use this as a starting point.

**Observations**

- given that the `foreach`es contain only one instruction (the `if`), they could be rewritten into `maps`, although I would not encourage that
- the `if` could also be rewritten using `ternary operator` and `print` the resulting string
- taking into consideration all of the above, the whole XML processing could be rewritten in a single line consisting of 3 `map`s and 2 ternary ops - I think it would be almost unreadable

Comment: i am using xml::libxml , so can u please write using xpath and xml::libxml . i am new to all these .
why i am getting errors?

Comment: foreach 
        $doc->findnodes(
            "//meters/meter"
            ."/name[../value[\@solve/string() = 'immediate']]"
            ."/text()");
i am getting these errors
XPath error : Undefined namespace prefix;
 error : xmlXPathCompiledEval: evaluation failed.
if i remove \ before @ , it is detecting as an array ... can any one solve it please?